# mySQL query how to select a value based on another column

Tags: mysql

I want to select the lecturer who teaches at least two distinct yearlevel.
For example, lecturer 222222 who teaches both yearlevel 2 and 9.
what query statement should I write in order to achieve that?
[image]

Comment: have you tried anything?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the lecturers by using  aggregate function count with a distinct filter for yearlevel and then filter your aggregate results using having clause

```
select lecturer
from table
group by lecturer
having count(distinct yearlevel) >= 2
```

Comment: Thanks! So what if I want to add one more condition to making sure one of the yearlevels has to be 9. Can I add that in having clause directly?

Comment: yes you can do it like in having clause after count part add  `and sum(yearlevel = 9)`

Comment: Thanks a lot for ur help!

Answer (score 0):

Two queries come to mind. The first borrows language from the question itself, and uses `COUNT DISTINCT` in a `HAVING` clause:

```
select lecturer                         -- "select the lecturer"
from myTable
group by lecturer
having count(distinct yearlevel) >= 2   -- "who teaches at least two distinct yearlevel"
```

The second is a special case which uses `EXISTS`. Since you are looking for two distinct yearlevels, we can rewrite this as "also teaching another yearlevel". This may be useful depending on how you want to project your result, and/or what the optimizer decides to do:

```
select *
from myTable a
where exists (
    select 1 
    from myTable b 
    where b.lecturer = a.lecturer 
    and b.yearlevel <> a.yearlevel)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for ur help!